# MySQL statement failing on local machine but not deployment machine?

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee

As part of work, I have been assigned to a massive Java EE project that has hundreds of SQL statements strewn throughout it.  I set up the project on my computer and have been able to deploy the website just fine and use 99% of it without issue. I came across one odd case though, and that's when I try to create an entry on the website (its a government-based form sort of project). MySQL throws an exception when the program tries to execute the query:

```
SELECT d.id, ..., dol.weight, d.status
FROM DeliveryOrderEJB d, InbondEJB_DeliveryOrderEJB_link lnk 
LEFT JOIN DOLineEJB dol 
    ON dol.id=(
        SELECT MIN(dol2.id) 
        FROM DOLineEJB dol2 
        WHERE d.id=dol2.DeliveryOrderEJB_lines
    ) 
WHERE d.id=lnk.DeliveryOrderEJB_id 
AND lnk.InbondEJB_itNo='...' 
ORDER BY d.id
```

The exception it gives me is `Unknown column 'd.id' in 'where clause'`

The part that I am confused about is why it seems to work fine on the production machine, and this appears to be the only one failing on my machine. The column clearly exists in the DeliveryOrderEJB table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure is referring to the `d.id` in the nested subquery:

```
ON dol.id=(
    SELECT MIN(dol2.id) 
    FROM DOLineEJB dol2 
    WHERE d.id=dol2.DeliveryOrderEJB_lines
)
```

You can fix the query:

```
SELECT d.id, ..., dol.weight, d.status
FROM DeliveryOrderEJB d join
     InbondEJB_DeliveryOrderEJB_link lnk 
     on d.id=lnk.DeliveryOrderEJB_id left join
     DOLineEJB dol 
     ON dol.id=(
        SELECT MIN(dol2.id) 
        FROM DOLineEJB dol2 
        WHERE d.id=dol2.DeliveryOrderEJB_lines
     ) 
WHERE lnk.InbondEJB_itNo='...' 
ORDER BY d.id
```

I believe the problem is because you have different versions of MySQL on the machines.  MySQL changed the semantics of the `,` around version 5.0.